# Unable to Truncate dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs

I am trying below line to slice content but its not working is it something i am doing

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: collabItem.ColloborationDescription.slice(0, 200)}} />
```

Comment: Can you be more specific that "not working"? What is happening that shouldn't? What isn't happening that should? What errors , if any, are thrown? Is there a chance that by truncating the item you are trying to set inner HTML with invalid HTML?

Comment: I created one function and used it its working now Thank you for help.